Counting commas in two columns and showing the count side by side
Based on the sample dataframe below how can I get the comma count of two columns?
Sample data:
 ID  City       Zipcode
  1   A,B,C,D    1,2,3,4
  2   A,B        1,2
  3   A          1
  4   B,C        2,3

Desired output:
City       Zipcode  City_Count Zipcode_Count
A,B,C,D    1,2,3,4  4          4
A,B        1,2      2          2
A          1        1          1
B,C        2,3      2          2

Code:
# Based on my research so far, below is what I have found to count values/commas in a single column

df['value_count'] = df.string_column.str.count(',')

print (df)


Use the same line of code twice? Once for each column?

Thank you but I would like to store the counts in a dataframe as two new columns as shown in the desired output.

You of course change the new column's name...

You can use:
df[['City_count', 'Zipcode_count']] = df[['City', 'Zipcode']].map(lambda x: x.count(','))

to give:
      City  Zipcode  City_count  Zipcode_count
0  A,B,C,D  1,2,3,4           3              3
1      A,B      1,2           1              1
2        A        1           0              0
3      B,C      2,3           1              1

I do not understand why your comma-count is 1 greater than the numnber of commas
